# Eslint parse error on comma dangle in functions

Tags: javascript, eslint

I couldn't find an answer to this question on SO (it might be there, I just couldn't find it), so I'm posting the question and the answer I finally found. I hope it helps.

When using a dangling comma on function calls, ESLint throws this error: `Parsing error: Unexpected token )`. The "unexpected token" is the function's closing paren.

I have `comma-dangle` set to `'comma-dangle': ['error', 'always-multiline']` in my `eslintrc` file.

Why would this error get thrown?

Just to clarify, this is what a dangling comma would look like in a function call:

```
const result = parseInput(
  input,
  true,
  paramNames, // this is the line with the dangling comma
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dangling commas in function calls were added in ECMAScript 2017 (yay!). In order for ESLint to recognize this new feature, you have to specify the `ecmaVersion` in `.eslintrc`. ECMAScript 2017 corresponds to `ecmaVersion` 8. So the setting would look something like this:

```
"parserOptions": {
  "ecmaVersion": 8
}
```

FYI, you can use any `ecmaVersion` greater than 8 as well.